# Adobe Animate CC - Clicks not working with a Video embedded

Tags: html5-canvas, createjs, animate-cc

I'm working on HTML5 canvas in Adobe Animate CC. Before embedding video I've created click actions and added links and since the video has been added (by Components > Video) all clickable objets stoped to work. Video is playing and slides and all animation is happening except interactive elements. I am feeling that the video is somehow embedded above everything (I have video layer at the very bottom).

Would you be able to help me please? Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Video isn't part of the canvas, it's DOM element and it's over HTML5 canvas by default. If you'll view Animate's generated HTML code you can see it (video tag in "dom_overlay_container" div).
You need to rearrange your project and keep in mind that you have other DOM elements too in addition to the canvas.